# maven or gradle: how to find the dependencies developer/provider(s)

Tags: gradle, maven-3

I am trying to collect the information of all third party modules we have used inside our app, which include name, version, latest version, license and provider. I can collect all of those info using mvn plug-in for the maven projects, but just cannot find a plug-in to list the providers (homepage or vendor info inside manifest). Is there any plug-in available?
Also we had some Gradle projects, what option is best to generate report without modifying the existing `build.gradle` file(s)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no direct analog to the tool you want. You can get some information via `dependencies` or `dependenciesInsight` tasks, but it won't provide, for example, licensing information.

The best way to generate a report about your build [without modifying any build files](https://guides.gradle.org/creating-build-scans/#auto_apply_the_build_scan_plugin), IMO, is [Gradle Build Scans](https://guides.gradle.org/creating-build-scans) feature. BTW, they also [support Maven](https://github.com/gradle/maven-build-scan-quickstart)!

Just append `--scan` to the invocation command and the report will be generated:

> Starting with Gradle 4.3, you can enable build scans without any additional configuration in your build script. When using the command line option --scan to publish a build scan, the required build scan plugin is applied automatically. Before the end of the build, you are asked to accept the license agreement on the command line. The following console output demonstrates the behavior.

```sh
$ ./gradlew build --scan

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 6s

Do you accept the Gradle Cloud Services license agreement (https://gradle.com/terms-of-service)? [yes, no]
yes
Gradle Cloud Services license agreement accepted.

Publishing build scan...
https://gradle.com/s/czajmbyg73t62
```

If you want a quick demo, here is a build scan report for one of my [public projects](https://gitlab.com/madhead/aws-junit5): https://scans.gradle.com/s/6fmoybczbores, explore it as you wish. It has a "Dependencies" section, still it has no licensing.

The other approach could be using a third-party tool that monitors the dependencies for you. One well-known is [Snyk](https://snyk.io), take a look, probably it will work for you. Probably one day GitHub will be able to track the dependencies too, but as of September 2019 it is [able to track](https://help.github.com/en/articles/listing-the-packages-that-a-repository-depends-on) only Maven projects:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will take a look at `--scan` option of gradle. Yes github reports the dependencies from `pom.xml`, however, currently it does not understand the parent pom which is not named as `pom.xml` so the version info is missing.